# Select #document object in JSON object

Tags: json, object

I have a JSON object that was generated from an XML document. When I console.log(object) the following can be seen:

```
Object {#document: Object}
```

How do I select the #document object?

Comment: One way to do it would be to JSON.stringify the object and remove the first 13 characters and the last character from the string and then convert it back into a string. However, I'm still looking for the direct method to select the #document object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var x = {"#document":{}};
console.log(x["#document"]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wfxnufpL/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
object.document
object['#document']
object['document']
```

If none of those work, you might have to decode your JSON first if it is still encoded:

```
newObject = JSON.parse(object);
```